# How to extract data out of csv with dynamic date column value with the help of mapping csv file using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm working with a csv files that has few columns with details like Name, Category, Sub Category and the dates as headers that varies depending on the selection. I want to reformat the data but couldn't figure out the way with less looping through the text of each records. I did create a mapping so use it for filtering reference but need some pointers to use it to avoid looping.

**Here's sample csv data I'm struggling with**

[image]

**Here's the mapping csv data**

[image]

I tried grouping the object but not able to understand how to re-arrange it in an expected way. I'm able to extract out dates from the header line.

**Here's my code:**

```
 $data = import-csv "C:\sample.csv"
$mapping = import-csv "C:\mapping.csv"

#get dates
$dates = (Get-Content $data | Select-String 'name').ToString().Split(',') | Select-Object -Skip 3

foreach ($date in $dates) {
    $data | Group-Object -Property Name | Foreach-Object {
        $_.Group | Group-Object -Property Category | ForeEach-Object {
            $_Group | Select-Object -Property * 
        }
    }

}
```

**This is the expected output:**

[image]

Comment: you have a valid CSV as input and want to turn it into something that cant be called CSV so you should start thinkin even before you get that desired output, how are you going to export that data cause `Export-Csv` just won't cut it.

Comment: Yeah Santiago, I'm thinking about having a separate export CSV file for each date. I'm just confused about how to implement the mapping to move ahead with creating the csv expoer files.